# Convert int array to Point in openCV java

Tags: java, android, opencv, java-native-interface

I am new to openCV. I have converted the Points detected in my JNI code to an int array and returned to my java program, here is the part of code from my jni program:

```
    jintArray result;
    jint fill[60];
    for(int k=0; k<30; k++){
        fill[2*k] = V[k].x;
        fill[2*k+1] = V[k].y;
    }
    result = env->NewIntArray(60);
    env->SetIntArrayRegion(result, 0, 60, fill);
    return result;
```

Now when  I try to convert the array back to Point in my java program it gives me this error: " java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'double org.opencv.core.Point.x' on a null object reference "

```
    Point[] featureArray = new Point[30];

    for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
        featureArray[i].x = featuresFill[2*i];
        Log.e("test x: ",""+featuresFill[2*i]);
        featureArray[i].y = featuresFill[2*i+1];
        Log.e("test y: ",""+featuresFill[2*i+1]);
    }
```

I have tried printing the int array and the features detected are printed out fine. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
featureArray[i] = new Point(featuresFill[2*i], featuresFill[2*i+1]);
```

instead